# No such table error when replacing a table through SQLalchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLalchemy and the pandas method `pd.to_sql(if_exists="replace")` to insert data in to a table in PostgreSQL.

Now, if the table doesn't exist, then everything works ok.

But, if the table already exists (I know it exists since I can see it in pgAdmin), I get the following error: `sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError:`

SQLalchemy is trying to drop this table to replace it with the new one, but it can't find the table for some reason?

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
ENGINE = create_engine(...)

with ENGINE.begin() as con:
   df.to_sql("table_name", con=con, index=False, if_exists="replace")
```

This throws the above error? I have tried specifying the schema but this also throws the same error.

Why isn't SQLalchemy finding the table even though it's there?

EDIT: If I remove the `if_exists="replace"`, I then get the error: `ValueError: Table tablename already exists.`

Comment: What is the actual table name? Have you looked at the Postgres logs to see what commands are being sent?

Comment: @the-man ran into the same issue, have you figured out?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue and figured out that the table exists with the below ddl :

create table table_name();

Please delete the table and try again it will work.